# NGINX Proxy behind Corporate Proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to test my frontend of a web-application locally and send requests to a my my server on the internet, but I'm behind a corporate proxy. Without proxy I can just use NGINX's proxy_pass and it works. Is it possible to tell NGINX to send the proxied request through another proxy?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I keep getting 502 bad gateway error. Have you got solution?